# I try to change font in ggplot but get the error " Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...", why?

Tags: r

I want to change font in ggplot, when I try to do this I get the following error. There seem to be some problem with .afm files to ttf. The fonts I have downloaded are in .afm files. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can solve it? Many thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
font_import(paths = "C:/Users/aaa/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/extrafontdb/metrics",prompt = F)

Scanning ttf files in C:/Users/elisen/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/extrafontdb/metrics ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

.........................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`extrafontdb`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=extrafontdb) seems to contain only extracted .afm files from the previous [`font_import()`](https://github.com/wch/extrafont#import-fonts-into-the-extrafont-database).

To load the fonts from the `extrafontdb` database you probably need to run:

```
extrafont::loadfonts()
```

See details in [documentation](https://github.com/wch/extrafont#register-the-fonts-with-the-pdf-output-device).

But for proper font import you still need to have a .ttf file, see [documentation](https://github.com/wch/extrafont#import-fonts-into-the-extrafont-database):

> .afm file contains the *font metrics*, which are the rectangular dimensions of each character that are needed for placement of the characters. These are not the *glyphs*, which the curves defining the visual shape of each character. The glyphs are only in the .ttf file.